# How to build large multiplexers using SystemVerilog?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, system-verilog, rtl

Note: This question about **multiplexers**
is similar to but not identical to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/552528/238188) which is about **demultiplexers**.

I want to build a fully parameterisable **multiplexer** in SystemVerilog. So far, I know how to build **multiplexers** of variable widths like this:

```vhdl
module scale_mux #(parameter WIDTH = 1) (
  input logic sel_a,
        logic [WIDTH-1:0] in_a,
                    in_b,
  output logic [WIDTH-1:0] out);

  always_comb
    unique case (sel_a)
      1'b1 : out = in_a;
      1'b0 : out = in_b;
    default: out = 1'bx;
    endcase

endmodule
```

I also know how to extend this for **4:1 and 8:1 multiplexers**. But the number of case statements for large **multiplexers** will be a lot.

I'd like to build a **multiplexer** in which the **number of inputs** is variable. I'm not sure how I can extend this case statement for the n input case, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vhdl
module generic_mux #(parameter WIDTH = 1, 
                     parameter NUMBER = 2, 
                     localparam SELECT_W = $clog2(NUMBER)) 
 (input logic [SELECT_W-1:0] sel, 
  input logic [WIDTH-1:0] mux_in [NUMBER-1:0],                   
  output logic [WIDTH-1:0] out);
  
  assign out = mux_in[sel];
    
endmodule
```

I used part select to select the input and route it to the output. The select line width is logarithm to the base 2 of the number of inputs. The select line width should be declared as `localparam` so that it won't be overridden.