# How to build large demultiplexers using SystemVerilog?

Tags: digital-logic, system-verilog, rtl

Note: This question about **demultiplexers** is similar to but not identical to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/552516/3288) which is about **multiplexers**.

I want to build a fully parameterisable **demultiplexer** in SystemVerilog. So far, I know how to build **demultiplexers** of variable widths like this:

```vhdl
module scale_mux #(parameter WIDTH = 1) (
  input logic sel_a,
        logic [WIDTH-1:0] in,
  output logic [WIDTH-1:0] out_a, out_b);

  always_comb
    unique case (sel_a)
      1'b1 : out_a = in;
      1'b0 : out_b = in;
    default: out = 1'bx;
    endcase

endmodule
```

I also know how to extend this for **1:4 and 1:8 demultiplexers**. But the number of case statements for large **demultiplexers** will be a lot.

I'd like to build a **demultiplexer** in which the **number of inputs** is variable. I'm not sure how I can extend the case statement for the n input case, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Russell McMahon, you'll vote to reopen it now, won't you?

Comment: I've reopened it. I think the similarity between the two questions is rather borderline. As people MAY search on multiplexer or demultiplexer I'll consider it different enough :-). There may be some comment on that.

Comment: Thank you for reopening it @RussellMcMahon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vhdl
module generic_demux #(parameter WIDTH = 1, 
                       parameter NUMBER = 2, 
                       localparam SELECT_W = $clog2(NUMBER)) 
 (input logic [SELECT_W-1:0] sel, 
  input logic [WIDTH-1:0] mux_in,                   
  output logic [WIDTH-1:0] out [NUMBER-1:0]);
  
  assign out[sel] = mux_in;
    
endmodule
```

I used part select to select the right output to which the input has to be routed. The select line width is logarithm to the base 2 of the number of inputs. The select line width should be declared as `localparam` so that it won't be overridden.